# ASSEMBLY: Binary Search on a Sorted String Array

Tags: c, assembly

After having spent several days on this binary search problem, which must be done completely in Assembly, I'm not quite sure where my logic breaks down when it comes to searching for name matches [case-insensitive] from a sorted array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated:

**THE C PROGRAM**

```
/*

int b_search (char list[100][20], int count, char* token);

list – the starting address of the list of names to be searched

count – total number of names in the list

token – name to be searched in the list

*/
```

This is the list of names:
Arturo Bryan chris David Jon Mark shane SIMON Thomas TONY

The following are all tokens, names to be searched in the list:

// tests elements with exact match, for example: "Jon", "shane", "TONY"

// tests case insensitivity, for example: "Chris", "BryAN"

// tests if code detects partial and nonsensical queries, for example: "Art" [short for Arturo], "garbage"

// tests a list with an odd number of names, for example: "DAVe", "Jona"

I've constantly been getting either infinite loops somewhere in the logic, finding
that the index returned is always 0 or finding that it incorrectly returns "name not found."

Again, any help would be greatly appreciated; thanks for reading.

// =================================================================================

MY CODE:

```
int b_search (char list[100][20], int count, char* token)
{
__asm
{
// Function returns the positionmove of the token in the list, starting with 1.

// If name is NOT found, return 0.

// Registers used:

// EAX: logical OR value

// EBX: toLowercase() loop counter

// ECX: total number of names

// EDI: name to be searched

// ESI: list pointer

mov eax, 0                      ; // zero out the result
mov ebx, 0                      ; // zero out EBX for use
mov esi, list                   ; // move the list pointer to ESI
mov edi, token                  ; // the name to be searched to EDI

// YOUR CODE HERE
// list - the starting address of the list of names to be searched
// count - total number of names in the list
// token - name to be searched in the list

// ==================================================================================================================
// CHANGE TOKEN LETTERS TO LOWERCASE
// ==================================================================================================================

TOKEN_LOWERCASE: // Cycles through every char in token and converts them to lowercase
    mov eax, [edi + ebx]        ; // move char of token into EAX
    or eax, 0x20                ; // convert to lowercase by logical OR with 0010 0000
    mov [edi + ebx], eax        ; // move new char back into EAX 
    inc ebx                     ; // increments loop counter
    cmp [edi + ebx], 0x00       ; // checks if the next char is a null terminator
jnz TOKEN_LOWERCASE             ; // exit loop in the presence of a null terminator

// ==================================================================================================================
// BINARY SEARCH RECURSION - FIRST ITERATION LOCATION
// All registers are now open except for EDI and ESI
// ==================================================================================================================

mov eax, 0                      ; // set the minimum value to be index first [0]
mov ecx, count                  ; // set the maximum value to be index last [index.length]
mov edx, 0                      ; // zero out EDX for use
push eax                        ; // push minimum value EAX back onto stack
push ecx                        ; // push maximum value ECX back onto stack

BEGIN_BINARY_SEARCH: // return here for recursion
    mov eax, 0                  ; // zero out EAX for use
    //mov ebx, 0                ; // zero out EBX for use
    mov ecx, 0                  ; // zero out ECX for use
    mov edx, 0                  ; // zero out EDX for use

    // FIRST IN, LAST OUT
    pop ecx                     ; // maximum value; first in, last out
    pop eax                     ; // minimum value; first in, last out
    cmp ecx, eax                ; // compares the maximum and minimum values
    jl DONE_EXIT                ; // all operations completed, goto DONE_EXIT [KNOWN ISSUE]
    mov edx, eax                ; // move EAX into EDX
    add edx, ecx                ; // add EAX and ECX, store it into EDX
    sar edx, 0x01               ; // shifts arithmetic right, dividing EDX by 2

    // FIRST IN, LAST OUT
    push eax                    ; // push minimum value EAX back onto stack
    push ecx                    ; // push maximum value ECX back onto stack
    mov eax, 0                  ; // move EAX to 0 for use *****
    mov ebx, 0                  ; // move EBX to 0 for use [external counter, see "RECURSION CONCLUDES"]
    mov ecx, 0                  ; // move ECX to 0 for use

    // ==============================================================================================================
    // INNER RECURSIVE LOOP
    // Registers to keep track of:
    // ECX = token[i]
    // EAX = element[i]
    // ==============================================================================================================
    GO_LOWER: // loop to check if cursor needs to go lower
        mov ecx, edx            ; // move EDX and copy it into ECX; SEE BELOW:
        imul ecx, 0x14          ; // OFFSET_TOTAL = COUNT * 20[Decimal]
        add ecx, ebx            ; // adds offset to EBX
        mov eax, [esi + ecx]    ; // moves element[i] into EAX, where list + 20 * externalCount + internalCount
        // ECX held the offset; it has been moved to EAX, so ECX can be reset
        mov ecx, 0              ; // reset ECX with every iteration to prepare for another address's contents
        mov ecx, [edi + ebx]    ; // move token element into ECX
        cmp eax, 0x00           ; // compares EAX to zero; checks for null terminator; SEE BELOW:
        jz NULL_TERM_CHECK      ; // if IS zero, then jump to IS_NULL
        jnz NOT_NULL            ; // if NOT zero, then jump to NOT_NULL

        // ==========================================================================================================
        NULL_TERM_CHECK: // procedure to check contents of ECX are a null terminator at this point
            //cmp ecx, 0x00     ; // checks for null terminator
            cmp ecx, eax        ; // compares token and element
        jz IS_MATCH             ; // if IS null terminator, then reached end of String
        jl DONE_GO_LOWER        ; // if token.length() is shorter then element.length()
        jg DONE_GO_HIGHER       ; // if token.length() is longer than element.length()
        //jnz DONE_EXIT         ; // if NOT null terminator, function is not yet finished; proceed:
        // ==========================================================================================================

        NOT_NULL: // proceed with the rest of the function
            or eax, 0x20        ; // logical OR with EAX will return the letter in lowercase
            sub ecx, eax        ; // -32 -> 0 -> +32; result indicates need to jump DONE_GO_LOWER or DONE_GO_HIGHER
        jl DONE_GO_LOWER        ; // jump to GO_LOWER if less than zero; 
        jg DONE_GO_HIGHER       ; // jump to GO_HIGHER if greater than zero
        inc ebx                 ; // increments loop counter if slips through
    jmp GO_LOWER                ; // return to GO_LOWER for recursion
    // ==============================================================================================================

// ==================================================================================================================
// RECURSION CONCLUDES - END ITERATION LOCATION
// Registers EAX, EBX and ECX are now open
// Register EDX is reserved for being the external loop counter
// ==================================================================================================================

// ==================================================================================================================
DONE_GO_LOWER:

    // FIRST IN, LAST OUT
    pop ecx                     ; // pop maximum value back into ECX from stack
    pop eax                     ; // pop minimum value back into EAX from stack
    mov ecx, edx                ; // move EDX into ECX, copying the value
    sub ecx, 0x01               ; // subtracts 1 from current makes the maximum
    push eax                    ; // push minimum value EAX back onto stack
    push ecx                    ; // push maximum value ECX back onto stack
jmp BEGIN_BINARY_SEARCH         ; // jump back to beginning of recursion

// ==================================================================================================================

// ==================================================================================================================
DONE_GO_HIGHER:

    // FIRST IN, LAST OUT
    pop ecx                     ; // pop maximum value back into ECX from stack
    pop eax                     ; // pop minimum value back into EAX from stack
    mov eax, edx                ; // move EDX into EAX, updating the minimum
    add eax, 0x01               ; // adds 1 to current makes the minimum
    push eax                    ; // push minimum value EAX back onto stack
    push ecx                    ; // push maximum value ECX back onto stack
jmp BEGIN_BINARY_SEARCH         ; // jump back to beginning of recursion

// ==================================================================================================================

DONE_EXIT:
    mov eax, 0                  ; // move eax back to 0 to finish up
    jmp DONE                    ; // jump to default done location

// ==================================================================================================================
IS_MATCH:
    mov eax, edx                ; // move ESP contents into EAX
jmp DONE                        ; // done with everything

// END PROCEDURE: DEFAULT TO HERE WHEN FINISHED

DONE: // ALL OPERATIONS FINISHED
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Edward is exactly right.  Here is a C routine that's not hard to translate.  My quick assembly version turned out to have 39 instructions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bsearch(char a[][20], int count, char *key)
{
  // Answer lies in a[lo .. hi-1].
  int lo = 0, hi = count;

  while (lo < hi) {

    // Midpoint of range where answer must lie.    
    int mid = (lo + hi) / 2;

    // This simulates condition codes for key comparison.
    int cmp;

    // Pointers and character values from key and midpoint strings.
    char *p_key = key, *p_mid = a[mid], ch_key, ch_mid;

    // Pointers advance together through key and midpoint strings, stopping at '\0'.
    for (;;) {

      // Fetch characters from key and array.
      ch_key = *p_key, ch_mid = *p_mid;

      // Break if null is found;
      if (ch_key == 0 || ch_mid == 0) break;

      // Convert to lower case if necessary.
      if ('A' <= ch_key && ch_key <= 'Z') ch_key += 'a' - 'A';
      if ('A' <= ch_mid && ch_mid <= 'Z') ch_mid += 'a' - 'A';

      // Break if inequality is found.
      if (ch_key != ch_mid) break;

      // Move to next character pair.
      p_key++;
      p_mid++;
    }
    // Set the condition codes based on character difference.
    cmp = ch_key - ch_mid; 

    // If equal, we're done.
    if (cmp == 0) return mid;

    // Shrink the range based on comparison result.
    if (cmp < 0) hi = mid;
    else         lo = mid + 1;
  }
  return -1;
}

int main(void) {
  static char a[][20] = {
    "Arturo", "Bryan", "chris", "David", "Jon", "Mark", "shane", "SIMON", "Thomas", "TONY"
  };
  static char keys[][20] = {
    "ARTURo", "brYAn", "cHRiS", "dAvID", "jON", "MaRk", "sHAne", "sImON", "THOmas", "TonY" , "AAAA", "foo", "ZZZZZ"
  };

  #define COUNT(A) (sizeof A / sizeof A[0])

  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < COUNT(keys); i++) {
    printf("%s: %d\n", keys[i], bsearch(a, COUNT(a), keys[i]));
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't mind but I am just interested to know that you people do assemby coding on which compiler/assembler.Please answer as I am going to have my assembly classes from this autumn! THANKS IN ADVANCE. Also,if not separate compiler,any tool or any inbuilt Linux,C,support,anything please...I'll be waiting for your response.

Comment: @shekharsuman You need to be able to use the tools you're given.  Pick one. Learn it well.  The others are not much different.

Comment: If you intend to write stand-alone programs or complete object files from assembly code, then NASM is fine.  If you want to write only a few lines for special purposes within a C/C++ program, then just focus on the inline `asm` statement in `gcc`. @shekharsuman

Comment: Thanks A Lot @Gene. You are a true mentor for novices like me.THANKS AGAIN!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with the code.  In no particular order, here's what I found:

### Altering the passed token

The code alters the token that was passed in, which may be acceptable, but you must check for a NUL terminator *before* you `or` the value with `0x20` and store it back in place.

Better would be to set the string to lowercase only when doing the comparison, leaving the passed string unaltered.

### Comments are not helpful

Lines like this:

```
mov edx, eax                ; // move EAX into EDX
```

are not helpful.  A programmer can see that the contents of EAX is being moved into EDX.  The comment should tell me *why* this is happening.

### Problems keeping track of register contents

When you have `mov ecx, 0` and two lines later `pop ecx` it tells me (and it should tell you!) that you're not keeping track of the contents of the register. Those are comments that will help you; I often write comment blocks above labeled lines (jump targets) that tell what I'm expecting to be in each register and on the stack.  You have that in a few places, but not all of the relevant registers are listed.  It really helps debugging code like this.  Ideally, you'd assign some purpose to each register and then use them only for that purpose in the entire rest of the code.

### Failure to lowercase the list entries

In the code after the `GO_LOWER` label, you're loading a letter of the next entry in the list into `eax` and the next letter of the token into `ecx` but only the latter has been converted to lowercase for comparison.

### Convoluted branching

These lines are overly complex:

```
    cmp eax, 0x00           
    jz NULL_TERM_CHECK     
    jnz NOT_NULL          
NULL_TERM_CHECK:
```

This could be very much simplified:

```
    cmp eax, 0x00           
    jnz NOT_NULL
```

Because the code will go to the next instruction anyway, you no longer need the other branch, and because it is used nowhere else, you can also eliminate the label.

### Binary search confusion

The intent appears to be to do a binary search, which typically starts in the middle of an ordered list and then does a comparison to figure out whether the item is in the top half or the bottom half of the range.  Your code appears to be starting from the first element rather than the middle and things can't work very well from there.

### General advice:

Try writing a correct and working routine in C and then replace a small portion at a time with the corresponding assembly language routine.  You'll spend less time debugging the basic algorithm and more time successfully implementing working assembly language code.